# what the composer patchLevel mean?

Tags: drupal, composer-php

I have an issue with `composer update` that creates `/b` directory in my project, I found some answers that suggested to set composer `patchLevel` to `-p2`. It works and fix my issue,

so what it means really and what is the difference between patchLevel  `-p1`, `-p2` ,`-p0` and `-p4`?

Answer (score 0):

> PatchLevel is for a specific release of a given major revision. The first release would be patch level 0. As bugs are fixed, each new releases would have a higher patch level number. If the patch level is the letter "x", it indicates a development snapshot (see [-Extra] immediately below for more information).

Drupal [docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/choosing-drupal-version/version-numbers).

Or translated, it's minor following semantic versioning where

```
<major> "." <minor> "." <patch>
```

in your (Drupal's) case semver's minor is Drupal's `patchLevel`

Comment: so what is `p` in the examples, `-p1` is the same as `patch-level 1`?

Comment: From same page: "PatchLevel is for a specific release of a given major revision. The first release would be patch level 0. As bugs are fixed, each new releases would have a higher patch level number." Without seeing your `composer.json` file and/or links to those answers it hardly can be told much more.

Answer (score 0):

The patchLevel is part of the git-apply command that composer uses in the background. `-p1` simply gets applied to the git-apply command. (The git manual doesn't call it patchLevel, but I will keep calling it like that in this answer because composer does so too.)

From `man git apply`:

> -p<n>
>
> Remove  leading path components (separated by slashes) from traditional diff paths. E.g., with -p2, a patch against a/dir/file will be applied directly to file.

When you don't specify a patch level, composer tries to apply the patch with different patch levels until the first one successfully applies. [[Source](https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches/blob/55c428957e791404ecfbe63c2bd9b43f57721550/src/Plugin/Patches.php#L401-L435)]. The order it does this in is `['-p1', '-p0', '-p2', '-p4']`.

Your patch only created a file, so applying the patch didn't fail, even though the patch was applied on the wrong level.